# Why is C standard bool not bool_t?

Tags: c, types, boolean

C's `stdbool.h` adds a `#define` for the type `_Bool` to bool.

I know a `#define` was used instead of a `typedef` to allow `#undef`-ing for legacy code clashes. But why wasn't `bool_t` (to match the other standard types) used in place of `bool`? Is the `_t` used for `typedef` types only?

I ask because the platform I am working on adds a typedef for `bool_t` to `_Bool`.

EDIT: *It's been correctly pointed out that the following is probably opinion based so consider it as only my reason for the primary question above.*

So I'm wondering should I use that or continue to use `bool`? I kind of like the way the former makes the boolean standard type form match the other standard types.

Comment: As a note, POSIX reserves `*_t`, this might be a technical reason to avoid `bool_t` (though I don't expect POSIX to define it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C introduced the `bool` macro (that expands to `_Bool`) with the C99 Standard. They probably chose the name `bool` instead of `bool_t` because C++ in 1998 named their boolean type `bool`. In C++98 all integral types (except `wchar_t` already in C90) don't use a `_t` suffix.

Comment: Additionally, there are other, earlier (than C++) existing uses of `bool` such as in X/Open Curses.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just found that the standard is inconsistent. `bool` is not the only type whose name does not have the `_t` suffix. Consider, for example, `<setjmp.h>`. It defines `jmp_buf` which is clearly a `typedef` yet does not end in `_t`.

I think the main reason why it's not `bool_t` is to make it look like it belongs to the family of standard types, `int` etc. However, they couldn't name the type `bool` due to compatibility purposes so hence the `_Bool`.

As for whether you should use `bool` or `bool_t` I think the question is rather opinion-based and cannot be answered just by using facts. However, I recommend you select one or the other and document that decision well in your coding guidelines.